# Извлечение из excel data

Tags: java, simpledateformat

1. Считываю эксель файл

XLSXReader reader = new XLSXReader(filename);
...

далее преобразую в список массива строк list
далее прохожусь по строкам и считываю в одной ячейке дату.
дата в самом эксель файле изначально записана в таком формате 
17.02.2017 00:00:00
после считывания получаю строку с таким значением
"42768" - т.е. java сама преобразовывает 17.02.2017 00:00:00 в это число.

я хочу создать метод который парсит значения из 42768 обратно в дату.
мой вариант не работает.

```
private String getDate(String datestr) { //42768
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        String s = sdf.format(sdf.parse(datestr));
        return s;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Fail, пробуем распарсить как эксель-дату
        try {
            return sdf.format(DateUtil.getJavaDate(Double.parseDouble(datestr)));
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

очень надо. помогите пожалуйста. нужно чтобы из экселя эта дата или считывалась нормально без преобразования в число. либо подскажите метод как обратно это число в дату превратить.

Comment: вообще, это [количество дней от "начала времен"](http://ericwhite.com/blog/dates-in-spreadsheetml/). Проблема в том, что вариантов начала два (1899-12-30 и 1904-01-01), поэтому лучше поищите в библиотеке, которой читаете файл, метод, который вернет вам сразу дату.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, согласен с zRrr, что лучше все-таки использовать уже разработанные для Вас утилиты. В данном конкретном случае [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) уже разработали целую линейку таких методов, например, [DateUtil.html#getJavaDate(double)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#getJavaDate(double)).

Также следует понимать причину такого поведения. А причина заключается в том, что excel представляет дату как количество дней начиная с 1 января 1900.

Но все же если Вам все-таки необходимо написать свой собственный код, то я бы все равно посоветовал взять наработки. Ниже приведен код, который сделаем необходимое конвертирование.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class ExcelDateToJava{
    public static final int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
    public static final int MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
    public static final int HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;
    public static final int SECONDS_PER_DAY = (HOURS_PER_DAY * MINUTES_PER_HOUR * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
    public static final long DAY_MILLISECONDS = SECONDS_PER_DAY * 1000L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int wholeDays = (int) Math.floor(42768);
        int millisecondsInDay = (int) ((42768 - wholeDays) * DAY_MILLISECONDS + 0.5);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        setCalendar(calendar, wholeDays, millisecondsInDay);
        System.out.print(calendar.getTime());
    }

    public static void setCalendar(Calendar calendar, int wholeDays, int millisecondsInDay) {
        int startYear = 1900;
        int dayAdjust = -1; // Excel thinks 2/29/1900 is a valid date, which it isn't
        if (wholeDays < 61) {
            // Date is prior to 3/1/1900, so adjust because Excel thinks 2/29/1900 exists
            // If Excel date == 2/29/1900, will become 3/1/1900 in Java representation
            dayAdjust = 0;
        }
        calendar.set(startYear, 0, wholeDays + dayAdjust, 0, 0, 0);
        calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, millisecondsInDay);
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения `Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 MSK 2017`

Надеюсь обе рекомендации помогут.